# SAGA Merge Vector Layers 'Add Source Information' not returning correctly

Tags: qgis, saga

Running "Processing -> Toolbox -> Saga -> Merge vector layers" in QGIS with 'Add source information' checked returns a merged file with an additional attribute "Source" but the values are a series of numbers (such as 1485259209.6737) rather than layer names. The number is the same for all the polygons in the same layer, but I don't know what this number refers to. I need the layer names or at least some way of identifying the source from that number. I have tried this with layers in .sqlite format and in .geojson format.

Comment: it maybe be an issue with databases. Did you try this method with normal shapefiles outside db?

Comment: haven't tried with shapefiles, but the .geojson are not in the db and the .sqlite are separate files not tables within in a single .sqlite file

Comment: I've now tried with shapefiles. Same problem with the Source attribute, although interestingly it made me realise that the previous merges were not bringing across the other attributes, whereas merging shapefiles brings across all attributives from all layers

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades I've just tried with two shapefiles and I see their name in the field "Source". Please, can you provide a sample of your files?